# Send music from specific application to certain sound output via command line

Tags: linux, pulseaudio

My use case:

I work out of my home office and maintain constant communication with my co-workers using a headset with some web conference service. In order to not be distracted or annoyed by certain outside noise I also play music from the same computer.

I want that music to be played through my hi-fi speakers. This way, I can have some discreet background music that doesn't interfere with my communication. Also, it helps me concentrating better.

I know that I can achieve this per-application sound redirect with `pavucontrol`. However, this application seems buggy in that it does not switch the default output (to later only route the music player to the other speaker). I have to use yet another mixer application (in my case the Cinnamon "Sound" applet) and need to switch between the two mixers to set it all up. And repeat all that in case the hi-fi looses it's connection or the music stops for some reason.

So, as I normally use one specific app to play music, I was looking for a way to *quickly* route *only* this app's sound output to my hi-fi.

Comment: You already solved your problem, but a comment on the Pulseaudio setup: Pulseaudio keeps a database of application-to-output mapping by default, and when an application starts, this database is used to find the output for the application. The "default output" is only used for new applications not yet in the database. And if the application does not properly identify itself, this can go wrong. `pavucontrol` just allows you to modify some Pulseaudio server setting, so it's not "buggy".

Comment: Thank you, @dirkt, for clearing that up. Indeed, `pavucontrol`s "set as fallback" feature seems to work differently than a "default output"-like feature in any other mixer I know. Unexpected for me, but hey, for others this might be an expected behavior.

Comment: Again: It's **not** a feature of `pavucontrol`, and `pavucontrol` is **not** the mixer. This all happens inside the Pulseaudio core, `pavucontrol` just gives you an UI to modify those things. You could also modify them with `pacmd` or `pactl`. And yes, many people are surprised by this behaviour of "default output", you are not the first.

Answer (score 2):

The following bash script solves the problem for my scenario. I use Brave Browser solely for music playback (while using other browsers for anything else). My hi-fi is some surround receiver connected via Bluetooth:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
# Collect all sinks
sinkList=$(pactl list sinks | tr '\n' '\r' | perl -pe 's/Sink #([0-9]+).+?device\.description = "([^\r]+)"\r.+?(?=Sink #|$)/\1:"\2",/g' | tr '\r' '\n')
IFS="," read -a sinksArray <<< "$sinkList"

# Is our Hi-fi sink available? → Use for loop with indexes to handle spaces in names
for ((i = 0; i < ${#sinksArray[@]}; i++)); do
  sink="${sinksArray[$i]}"
  #echo "sink found: $sink"

  # Search for this output device's name
  [[ "$sink" =~ "Philips HTB" ]] && hifiSinkIndex=$(echo $sink | cut -d':' -f1)
done

if [[ $hifiSinkIndex ]]; then
  echo "Hi-fi sink has index $hifiSinkIndex"

  # Collect all sound streams
  musicSourcesList=$(pactl list sink-inputs | tr '\n' '\r' | perl -pe 's/Sink Input #([0-9]+).+?application\.process\.binary = "([^\r]+)"\r.+?(?=Sink Input #|$)/\1:\2\r/g' | tr '\r' '\n')

  for soundSource in $musicSourcesList; do
    binary=$(echo $soundSource | cut -d':' -f2);
    index=$(echo $soundSource | cut -d':' -f1);
    #echo "index: $index, binary: $binary";

    # Brave browser is our music player, so we only care about that
    if [[ "$binary" == "brave" ]]; then
      echo "moving Brave output to $hifiSinkIndex"
      pactl move-sink-input $index $hifiSinkIndex
    fi
  done
else
  echo "Hi-fi sink was not found"
fi
```

The script can easily be adjusted as to which speaker name and application to look for.

I added a shortcut to this script to my panel for single-click run only when needed.

`pactl` comes with the package `pulseaudio-utils`. With `pacmd`, the commands would be similar.

Sources and inspirations:

- original `pacmd` queries: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070534/7200293) by phil294
- for loop over array values with spaces: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084479/7200293) by Dan Fego